# Make Logback not *follow the classes inheritance*

Tags: java, inheritance, logback

`remote.error.SuperClass`

```java
package remote.error;

public class SuperClass {

    public SuperClass() {
        // getClass() cannot be changed since belongs to a third party lib
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).debug("should NOT be printed");
    }

}
```

`local.debug.SubClass`

```java
package local.debug;

public class SubClass {

    public SubClass() {
        super(); // explicit for the example
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).debug("should be printed");
    }

}
```

`logback.xml`

```xml
<configuration>

    <!-- ... -->
    <logger name="remote.error" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="local.debug" level="DEBUG" />

</configuration>
```

With the above Logback configuration, **should NOT be printed** will still be printed (besides **should be printed**).

Is there any way to configure Logback to no *follow the classes inheritance*?

In other words, only **should be printed** should be printed, because *SuperClass* has the level **ERROR**.

Answer (score 1):

Consider one of the following:

1. Create an appender that does nothing and configure this appender for the SuperClass logger.
2. Create a filter that blocks all log messages from the SuperClass logger.
3. Configure the level of the SuperClass logger to "OFF".

Here is some code for option 3:

### SuperClass.java

```
package com.learn;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SuperClass
{
    private static final Logger logger =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(SuperClass.class);

    public SuperClass()
    {
        logger.info("should not show");
    }
}
```

### SubClass.java

```
package com.learn;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SubClass
extends SuperClass
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SubClass.class);

    public SubClass()
    {
        logger.info("should show");
    }

    public void hoot()
    {
        logger.info("hoot");
    }
}
```

### Main.java

```
package com.learn;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] arguments)
    {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();

        subClass.hoot();
    }
}
```

### logback.xml

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

    <logger name="com.learn.SuperClass" level="OFF"/>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The base class should be passing a statically-referenced class to logback, instead of the result of the virtual function getClass().

So `SuperClass.class` instead of `this.getClass()`

If, as you say, you can't change the base class, or raise a bug report to get someone to change it, then your only choice is to change the derived class. So put `SubClass` in package `remote.error.local`, but have it pick up it's own logger from a call to [the string overload of getLogger](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html#getLogger%28java.lang.String%29), with the arbitrary string you want, e.g.

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("local.debug")
```

Comment: The probleme is that SuperClass belongs to a third party library, i.e. cannot be modified...